# How to check if a feature macro has effect?

Tags: c, gcc, autoconf

In C, what is the correct way to check if a feature macro has any effect?

For example, if `configure.ac` contains the macro `AC_USE_SYSTEM_EXTENSIONS` then it will define `_GNU_SOURCE` on whatever OS. However, if we compile on OSX then `_GNU_SOURCE` will not have any effect. But on GNU systems it does, so how can I check if _GNU_SOURCE enables a feature, such as `qsort_r`?

`man feature_test_macros` says I should not include `features.h`, since it could be different on every system, meaning I can not use `__USE_GNU`.

The other option would be to check if `__GNUC__` is defined, or possibly if both `__GNUC__` and `_GNU_SOURCE` are defined?

Comment: How about adding a `configure.ac` check for the special functions? If it doesn't exist, even though the feature macro is defined, then it doesn't exist.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, this might  not be such a bad idea because you can of course use e.g. clang to compile on Linux which does not define `__GNUC__`.